# RichTextBox contents are not updated while saving

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a list box control in my form which contains the paths of files of particular type from a folder.
On item double click i am adding the page dynamically to the tab control and loading the contents of a file to the object of rich text box. Now i want to edit the contents and save it again . But when i open the saved file the edited contents are not saved it only has earlier contents which were there while loading the file to rich text box.How to update the rich text box object text and save.

```
 private void lstErrorList_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            ArrayList errorType = new ArrayList();
            RichTextBox myrich = new RichTextBox();
            string[] list;

            TabPage selectedTab;

            if (lstErrorList.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                string error = lstErrorList.SelectedItem.ToString();
                int result = error.LastIndexOf('\\');
                string filename = error.Substring(result + 1, error.Length - (result + 1));
                list = error.Split(new char[] { '\t' });
                int pagecount;
                TabPage tp = new TabPage();
                pagecount = this.tabControl1.TabPages.Count;
                bool found = false;
                foreach (TabPage tab in tabControl1.TabPages)
                {
                    if (filename.Equals(tab.Name))
                    {
                        tabControl1.SelectedTab = tab;
                        found = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (!found)
                {
                    tabControl1.TabPages.Add(filename, filename);
                    tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabControl1.TabPages[tabControl1.TabPages.Count - 1];
                    int i = tabControl1.TabPages.Count;
                    myrich.Height = this.tabControl1.Height - 30;
                    myrich.Width = this.tabControl1.Width - 10;
                    myrich.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Bottom);
                    tabControl1.TabPages[tabControl1.TabPages.Count - 1].Controls.Add(myrich);
                    string path = list[7];
                    objReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(path);
                    myrich.Text = objReader.ReadToEnd();
                    objReader.Close();
                }

                int val = 0;
                string val1 = list[3];
                string replacement = Regex.Replace(val1, @"\t|\n|\r|[a-zA-Z]", "");
                val = Convert.ToInt32(replacement);
                foreach (Control ct in tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls)
                {
                    if (ct is RichTextBox)
                    {
                        RichTextBox x = (RichTextBox)ct;

                        x.Select(val, wordToFind.Length);
                        x.SelectionBackColor = Color.Wheat;
                        x.Focus();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
 private void mnuValidate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {                      
            myrich.Refresh();
            myrich.Update();           
            foreach (TabPage page in tabControl1.TabPages)
            {                
                    string Saved_File = "";                
                    saveFD.Title = "Save the file";
                    saveFD.FileName = ChosenFileName;
                    saveFD.Filter = "Text File|*.txt|Html File|*.html|Xhtml File|*.xhtml|XML File|*.xml";
                    Saved_File = saveFD.FileName;
                    foreach (Control ct in tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls)
                    {
                        if (ct is RichTextBox)
                        {
                            int x = tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.IndexOf(ct);
                            MessageBox.Show(x.ToString());
                            ((RichTextBox)page.Controls[x]).SaveFile(Saved_File,RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);                          

                        }        
}


                    this.tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(page);   


            }           
            lstErrorList.Items.Clear();
            if (filePathlist.Count == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No input files found,Please upload files and validate again", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            else
            {
                if (HTML_QC_MultipleFiles.Errors.Checkeditemlist.Count == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please select the error type and validate again", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (singlefile == true)
                    {
                        Validate();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        bool errorFound = false;
                        string[] words;
                        foreach (string file in filePathlist)
                        {
                            int lineno, index;
                            objReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(file);
                            myrich.Clear();
                            myrich.Height = this.tabControl1.Height - 30;
                            myrich.Width = this.tabControl1.Width - 10;
                            myrich.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Bottom);
                            myrich.Text = objReader.ReadToEnd();
                            ChosenFileName = file;
                            Validate();
                            objReader.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem *could* be that your code asks for a the filename to save as and then iterates through the set of controls saving each to the same file. If you have two rich text boxes then it could be the efforts of saving the first are overwritten by the second.

Other things to look out for:

- Is there an exception during save?
- Is the file definitely being saved with the same name as the first?
- Why does you save dialog filter to *.rtf, *.txt and *.html when the `SaveFile` method only saves RTF?
- Path manipulations should normally be done via the [`System.IO.Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) class.
- Consider introducing methods/functions for particular activities so that you don't end up with such large, wall-of-code methods.

Comment: The name of the file to save  is same as the name of the file in the open folder dialog. that the the file is overwritten. There is no exception.Yes the the file definitely being saved with the same name as the first. i want to save files of type *.rtf,*.txt,*.html and *.xhtml files only.i am saving the path in an arraylist and retrieving it at the time of saving.

Comment: Another thing is that if i edit the contents of  a richtextbox then the edited contents are saved. where as if i create the object of richtextbox and edit the contents  of object the edited contents are not saved.

Comment: @ManojNayak: 'edit the contents of object' -- by which property are you editing its contents?

Comment: the problem got solved .. As you said there was a mistake in the file path.. the contents are saved in another file.